# Многопоточность.Некорректное значение переменной a

Tags: java, многопоточность

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создаю 5 потоков,каждый увеличивает переменную на 5 тысяч.В итоге получается некорректный результат.
Попробовал синхронизировать потоки,не помогло,почему ?

P.S Я знаю,что можно создать отдельный класс MyInteger с полем int value внутри и создать метод IncrementValue(),но хочу разобраться почему именно этот код не работает корректно.

Comment: А разве вам IDE не подсказывает ответ на этот вопрос? Присмотритесь, там предупреждение светится) [Вот тут](https://habrastorage.org/webt/6x/a6/fz/6xa6fz28fv_uyurakrxh2wbt6my.png)

Comment: Значок на  41 строке говорит о том,что я переопределяю метод,лампочка на 11 строке относится к комментарию,так что к сожалению нет :-(

Comment: А жёлтый фон на 42й строке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Solution.a++;
```

создает новый объект `Integer`.

Comment: Блин,как можно было забыть что обёртки неизменяемы!Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
synchronized (Solution.a.getClass())
```

Потому что см. предыдущий ответ ))

Я бы советовал создать ОДИН `Runnable` для всех ваших потоков и синхронизировать его метод `run()` или же в этом методе `run()` оставить как у вас секцию `synchronized`, но синхронизировать ее по `this` (ну или по классу, как я предложил).